# Can I trigger Region Monitoring when I receive a Push Notification while app in BackGround?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, cllocationmanager

I have a requirement where I need to send a message to a user if that user is available in a certain location region. Even if the app is on the background through push-notifications I need to add a region to **Region Monitoring** and trigger the server to send the message to user the user once the user enters the Region. Is this possible while the app is in 
**Background** or **suspended**.

Or is it possible for the push notification itself to register Region Monitoring event without direct app involvement?

Thanx in advance for any answers. And pardon my novice nature of asking.

Comment: I think not for background,